# How can I change containers without losing quality?

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere, container

Trying Premiere Pro but can't seem to let me import .mkv or .mp4... So, I wonder if it's possible to just change containers without losing any quality at all.

Let's say a .mov container? Video is H.264, so it doesn't leave me with a lot of options..

Comment: I'm ot familiar with .mov, but "to change containers" without changing the video/audio tracks, is usually equivalent to "demux + mux", I suggest you search by those terms.

Comment: mp4 is almost synonymous with mov. Try just changing the extension. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#History_of_MP4

Answer (score 2):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) can change the container of a video file.

1. From the "Media" menu select "Convert/Save"
2. Select the source file (.mkv/.mp4)
3. From the "Convert" dialog you'll want to create a new profile

   1. On the new profile select "mp4/mov" for encapsulation
   2. On the video tab select "keep original track"
   3. If your files have audio, on the audio tab select "keep original track"
   4. Give your profile a name and click "Create"
4. Select the profile from the dropdown
5. Select the destination file path
6. Click "Start"